# How to access iOS native types?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Inherited and trying to update a Nativescript project. It looks like the dev before me was accessing the iOS native PDFKit in order to handle PDFs, but the typing is giving an error "Cannot find name 'PDFDocument'"

All that is happening is that a variable is being declared inside my .ts file:
`private _document: PDFDocument;`

Is there something that needs imported? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following code in your `references.d.ts` when you are using Nativescript 7+. This should let you get the typings for `PDFKit` including `PDFDocument`.

```js
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@nativescript/types-ios/index.d.ts" />
```